# How to modify this JavaScript regex to check for a person's valid name?

Tags: javascript, regex

This JavaScript regex checks to see if a person has entered a valid username:

```
var regexp = "/^[a-z]([0-9a-z])+$/i";
if(!regexp.test(name)) 
  return "Name may consist of letter, numbers and start with a letter." );
```

But I want to check whether the person has entered a valid name.

In other words:

```
Cher
Michael Jackson
Mary J. Blige
François Truffaut
```

I can't think of any cases where anything other than letters and maybe a period would be valid in a person's name.

I want to reject any other types of punctuation as a validation mistake.

But I want to make sure that, for example, `François Truffaut` would not be rejected because he has that funny version of the letter c that the French use.

How would I do this in a Javascript regex

Comment: Shouldn't single quotes be permissible? E.g. Shawn O'Reilly.

Comment: Or hyphens: Mary-Kate Olsen.  I think you may be attempting to over-engineer a solution that is just going to annoy your users.

Answer (score 4):

Why not try to disallow just the punctuation you don't want in the name, probably a shorter list.

```
var regexp = "/^[\\\/$&^!@#%*~\?\[\]=\_\(\)]/"
```

That may not be a complete list but it should be a short list.  These were the ones that seemed, the most reasonable IMO.

Comment: didn't work for me here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html

Answer (score 1):

Try `[\d\w.]+`.  It should take care of those funny French characters.  Test it [here](http://rubular.com/r/CuKFYhpZ7g) online (it's for ruby, but it's almost the same).

`[\d\w.][\d\w. ]*[\d\w.]` would take the full name, including possible spaces in the middle.  Limits the name length to two though.  But it should be ok.

Comment: Why `\d` and `\w` if you're using `.`?

Comment: When it's inside `[]` it actually means `.`.

Answer (score -1):

Enforcing character restraints on a name is a bad idea.

Comment: Enforcing character restrictions on a **username** is a very good idea, actually.

Comment: But the question isn't about usernames. This however, doesn't answer the question and should be a comment.

Comment: Agree that the answer doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @David Dorward: Are you sure? The first sentence states _"This JavaScript regex checks to see if a person has entered a valid username"_.

Comment: Oh good grief. OP, just because I didn't provide you with exactly what you **want** to hear does not mean what I said is off-basis. And sorry that I did not post as a comment.  Next time I'll know.   @elusive, I was answering based on "But I want to check whether the person has entered a valid name."